# Unable to use Quicksand.js filter within limited container space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, filter, responsive-design, quicksand

can anyone help? I've been racking my brain a week or so now.

Basically I'm trying to add a gallery to a page that uses twitter-bootstrap and the quicksand.js plugin. I figured it would be easy to implement since I found this nice site template from DXThemes. Here is the demo. http://demo.dxthemes.com/html/tabulate if you click portfolio 4 col. That is what I'm after.

The gallery needs to have 4 columns. In the bootstrap.css and style.css there are multiple containers for different sizes and etc. for responsive design that I've been playing with and modifying.

I've tried getting it to work within the page I created but there doesn't seem to be enough space available for the container to actually do the filter effect. Nothing I've done seems to work. I've changed margins, widths and etc. for the containers and rows from the original css files to make the container smaller to fit within the space.

It worked just fine during my testing phase without putting it within the page it needs to go in. Here is the test page I'm trying to insert to.

http://www.hlipublishing.com/nmg/myscratch.html

If anyone can help me out with this would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I scrapped the modified styles and replaced with the originals, now it seems to be working. Not exactly sure what the problem was but it seems to have something to do with the width of the container. If it's not exact, it won't work. So I'll have to go back and re-style.

[Working version](http://www.hlipublishing.com/nmg/myscratch-works-at-home.html)